# Need help converting a multi-language regular expression to detect a numeric range

Tags: regex

I've created a regular expression that matches any numeric value (with leading or trailing spaces) that contains ascii or arabic characters. Now I need to modify it to only match a certain range of values (e.g. 1900-1950).

```
(^\s*-?\d+\s*$)|(^\s*-?[\u0660-\u0669]+\s*$)
```

I'm pretty stuck. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that's really a bad use for a regular expression - a much easier (and simpler to maintain!) approach would be to match any number, and then do a simple comparison in the code to check if it's within the range you want.

As a side note, do you really want to include the spaces in the match?  Wouldn't it make more sense to move the \s* outside of the parens?

Comment: You're right, moving the spaces outside of the parens is a good call. I also think doing the range check in code is a good idea. This started as just a check for numeric values, which was great for a regular expression. When the range constraint needed to be added I didn't even think to consider another approach.

Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you posted, but if I'm understanding you right you have a character class that is acceptable between digits of a numeric value, so that "19fhuerfn4dsfjkw0" would match as it is 1940 with characters in between?

So given the character class that you want to match ([class]), you could just do this?

1[class]*9[class]*[0-4][class]*[0-9]*

If your number range isn't perfectly aligned with base 10, you may need to modify with a couple ors...like to make this one be 1900-1950 instead of 1900-1949 you would need to include a separate case for ending with 50.

Edited to add: 
It would maybe be easier to just parse through the input character by character. Ifg it's not a digit, strip it out. When the non-digits are stripped out, parse the remaining characters as an integer and do your range check. Then check if all the stripped out characters match your accepted class with a regexp.

19sdfh2djf3
/
sdfhdjf + 1923
/
match(sdfhdjf) && (1900 <= 1923 <= 1950)